# Combinatorial interpretation of a generating function (infinite product)

Tags: combinatorics, generating-functions, infinite-product

What is the combinatorial interpretation of the coefficient of the $n^{th}$ term in the following infinite product

$\Pi_{k\geq 1}(1+z^k)$

I know it should somehow related to the number of partition, but I don't know exactly what it is. Also the infinite product just confuses me, since there is no bound on the number it is counting.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: @Muralidharan Do they have to be distinct?

Answer (score 3):

The coefficient of $z^n$ in $\Pi_{k\geq 1}(1+z^k)$ is the number of ways in which we can write $n$ as a sum of distinct positive integers. See [A000009](https://oeis.org/A000009)

Since
$$\prod_{k\geq 1}(1+z^k)=\frac{\prod_{k\geq 1}(1-z^{2k})}{\prod_{k\geq 1}(1-z^{k})}=\frac{1}{\prod_{k\geq 1}(1-z^{2k-1})}$$
it is also the number of ways in which we can write $n$ as a sum of odd positive integers (not necessarily distinct).

Comment: Why do they have to be positive? Since we have infinite product, then $1z^n$ would also be acceptable, right?

Comment: @metricspace Here we consider only positive integers otherwise any number $n$ has infinite representations: $n=n+0=n+0+0=\dots$

Comment: But we also require the partition to be distinct, so $n+0+0...$ would not be acceptable right?

Comment: OK. But then $1$ and $1+0$ are TWO acceptable representations of $1$ whereas the coefficient of $z$ is ONE

Comment: Oh, okay, thanks!